# Delete from mongodb using php based on two conditions

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to do something like below:

```
  $result = $videos->deleteOne([
            'video_name' => $data->name,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        ]);
```

Will it work like this? I want to delete a record that has that userId and also the video_name. Now the thing is it is deleting something. Because i had 50 records and when i press delete i had 49 then again 48 but not the record that should have been deleted! So my suspicion is on the condition coz i m not used to php that much. How to rewrite that so that it deletes only when both conditions are met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was working but deleting some other videos so I had to tack on another unique identifier turning it into essentially.

```
 $result = $videos->deleteOne([
            'video_name' => $data->name,
            'user_id' => $user_id
             'job_id' => $data->jobID
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they are removed if both conditions are met, if not you can find first and then execute delete over that entity by using the _id

```
$entity = $videos->findOne([
    'video_name' => $data->name,
    'user_id' => $user_id
]);


$result = $videos->deleteOne([
    '_id' => $entity->_id
]);
```

Comment: that feels like unnecessary as in node js i could just do 
```db.collectionName.remove({'_id':12,'browser':"GC"})``` so there must be something similar in php .

Comment: and findOne is working as well like i get the unique document but i dont know why it cant delete it like this .